# Make list scrollable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using the   element to show a list of users. I also want to show a Ok button bellow the list. Currently I have to scroll to the end of the list to see the Ok button. How can I make it so that the list will take up a certain height and is scrollable while showing the ok button?

```
<v-card-text>
   <v-list >  
      <v-list-item
        v-for="user in users":key="user.id" >
       <v-list-item-content>
         user.name
        </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
   </v-list>
</v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="#9da4cf" text @click="save">Save</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
```

Comment: give the list a fixed height and make it scrollable aka overflow-y: scroll

Comment: @Paolo- Thanks. It worked